# Inverting the order of a Table - Prime numbers

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, prime-numbers

In a previous post I asked for the possibility to have a binary image of the coprimality inside the natural numbers. The following code

```
     TableForm[
     table = Table[Boole[CoprimeQ[m, n]], {m, 13}, {n, 13}],
     TableHeadings -> {Range[13], Range[13]}]
```

together with

```
     table == Table[Boole[GCD[m, n] == 1], {m, 13}, {n, 13}]

     (* True *)

     ArrayPlot[table, FrameTicks -> {Range[13], Range[13]}]
```

provides the following the result

[image]

Unfortunately, I need a plot as given below.

[image]

The problem is that the vertical axis should go from 1 to 13 and not vice versa. Any idea or tip?

Comment: `Reverse`.....?

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit that removed the contents of your question. Since somebody put in effort to answer your question, you should leave it intact so their answer makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Use the option [`DataReversed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataReversed.html):

```
ArrayPlot[table, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Range[13], Range[13]}, 
 DataReversed -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

```
table2 = Table[Boole[And @@ PrimeQ[{m, n}]], {m, 13}, {n, 13}];
ArrayPlot[table2, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Range[13], Range[13]}, 
   DataReversed -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]